# Open quotient of second countable space is second countable

Tags: general-topology

If $Y$ open and $X$ has countable basis, then $X/Y$ has a countable basis.

This is a review problem for my midterm, and Wikipedia says it's true. However, I cannot find a simple proof anywhere. (At this link http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/quotient-topology/ there is overkill.)

Comment: Please provide some of your own ideas on the problem.

Comment: $X/Y$ is $X$ where $Y$ is identified to a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $U_i$ are your countable basis for $X$, i.e. any open in $X$ is a union of $U_i$. Call the quotient map $\pi: X \rightarrow X/Y$.

For $X/Y$, consider the following opens: take $U'_i$ to be $\pi (U_i)$ if $U_i \cap Y = \emptyset$, and otherwise take $U'_i = \pi (U_i \cup Y)$.

Now for any open $V$ in to $X/Y$, to see the $U'_i$ work, simply pull it back to $X$, and check that if $\pi^{-1} V = \cup_{i \in J} U_i$, then $V = \cup_{i \in J} U'_i$.